# Three.js move camera from a vector to another

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have made a simple scene and referenced http://www.96methods.com/2011/12/three-js-moving-the-camera/ for moving a camera:

```
var timer = new Date().getTime() * 0.0005; 
camera.position.x = Math.floor(Math.cos( timer ) * 200);
camera.position.z = Math.floor(Math.sin( timer ) * 200);
```

However, it only circle the camera and i found it difficult to move from one vector to another vector with a designated speed. 
For example, camera point is (0,0,0), i want to move to (100,0,100), camera will face at that point and move to that point.
Any way to implement it by code or i just missed any official function? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd find a lot of use here with [tween.js](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/):

```
new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position )
  .to( {
    x: position.x,
    y: position.y,
    z: position.z}, 2000 )
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.EaseInOut)
  .start();
```

This example will move the camera to the position defined by x, y, z and take 2000 ms (2 seconds). There are a large number of transition effects included that will make your animation look very smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, in addition i found it can be solved by coding

```
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(moveVectors[currentIndex][0] * ((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000) + camera.position.x * (1-((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000)), moveVectors[currentIndex][1] * ((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000) + camera.position.y * (1-((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000)) , moveVectors[currentIndex][2] * ((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000) + camera.position.z * (1-((time - moveBaseTime+1)/100000))));
camera.position.x = moveVectors[currentIndex][0] * ((time - moveBaseTime)/100000) + camera.position.x * (1-((time - moveBaseTime)/100000));
camera.position.y = moveVectors[currentIndex][1] * ((time - moveBaseTime)/100000) + camera.position.y * (1-((time - moveBaseTime)/100000));
camera.position.z = moveVectors[currentIndex][2] * ((time - moveBaseTime)/100000) + camera.position.z * (1-((time - moveBaseTime)/100000));
```

Where the theory is set the timer, by the time passing the timer will reach to 1. So, the equation should: CURRENT_POSITION*(1-timer) + TARGET_POSITION*timer ; as timer is increasing from 0 to 1, current position*(1-timer) will become zero, and target position*timer will be target position.